# Modify li:after from content script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked around and tried a few things, but nothing has seemed to work. I apologize if this has already been answered before, but this has stumped me.

I'm trying to modify the css of an "li:after" from a JS/JQuery content script in a Chrome extension, to remove a box-shadow. I don't have direct access to the HTML/CSS of the webpage that I'm editing.

Could someone steer me in the right direction of learning how to do this?

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Testing",
  "description": "CSS Website Manipulation",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "scripts.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

scripts.js

```
changeCSS(window.location.href);

function changeCSS(url) {
    switch (url) {
        case "URL REDACTED": {
            // Change the look of the Username/Password input fields
            $('#user_id, #password').css({
                'border': 'none',
                'background-color': '#E8E8E8',
                'border-radius': '0',
                'color': '#232323',
                'outline': 'none',
                'box-shadow': 'none'
            });
            // Change the background of the page
            $('.login-page').css({
                'background': 'none',
                'background-color': '#F7F7F7',
                'color': 'white'
            });
            // Change the look of the announcement list items
            $('#loginAnnouncements > ul > li').css({
                'background-color': '#E8E8E8',
                'color': '#232323'
            });
            $('strong').css('color', '#009688');
            // Change the look of the Login button + fix the alignment to match the input fields
            $('#entry-login').css({
                'background': 'none',
                'border': 'none',
                'border-radius': '0',
                'background-color': '#009688',
                'margin-top': '9px',
                'margin-left': '-9px',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'text-decoration': 'none',
                'text-shadow': 'none',
                'box-shadow': 'none'
            });
            // Align the labels with the input fields
            $('#loginFormList > li > label').css({
              'margin-left': '-9px'
            });
            // Change the look of the buttons on the top right of the page
            $('.font-size .contrast').css({
              'border': 'none'
            });
            // Remove Capitalization from Username/Password labels
            $('#loginFormList > li > label').css('text-transform', 'none');
            $('#loginFormList > li > label').attr('autocapitalize', 'off');
            $('h2:first-of-type, .font-size, .contrast').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

styles.css

```
#loginAnnouncements ul li::after {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you debug your CSS and see why it's not applying? Do you know about using `!important` to increase the priority of lines of CSS for overrides?

Comment: I've tried creating an li.special class and then toggling that on the li element, to no avail. As for !important, I have never used that.

Comment: Start with something like this: `li::after { box-shadow: none !important; }`

Comment: That did not work either.

Comment: Can you provide code so we can help?

Comment: Updated post with all of my code. I'd rather not disclose the webpage I'm editing for privacy reasons if that's alright.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to modify the css of an "li:after" from a JS/JQuery content
>   script in a Chrome extension, to remove a box-shadow. I don't have
>   direct access to the HTML/CSS of the webpage that I'm editing.

Nevertheless... you have javascript access to the CSS stylesheet of the webpage you are editing:

```
var lastRule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length;
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('#loginAnnouncements ul li::after { box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none;}', lastRule);
```

You can use `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule` to dynamically edit the document's stylesheet.

The second argument of `insertRule()` determines where in the stylesheet your new rule will be inserted.

In this case, `lastRule` ensures the new rule will be inserted at the very end of the stylesheet, at the bottom of the existing cascade.

Comment: Odd thing: The area of which it's getting the li:after is on a stylesheet that is not being loaded in the head section.